# pymongo insert timestamp validation error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with the given schema:

```
 {
            "name" : "check3",
            "type" : "collection",
            "options" : {
                "validator" : {
                    "$jsonSchema" : {
                        "bsonType" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "TIMEDESC" : {
                                "bsonType" : "timestamp"
                            },
.............
...........
```

when I try to insert a document I get validation error:

```
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['poc']
data = {
    'TIMEDESC': datetime.datetime.now()
}
mycol = db['check3']
x = mycol.insert_one(data)
```

> pymongo.errors.WriteError: Document failed validation, full error:
> {'index': 0, 'code': 121, 'errmsg': 'Document failed validation'}

Answer (score 0):

The bsonType you need to store dates is "date".

Answer (score 0):

The [MongoDB Timestamp docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) note that:

> The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type. See Date for more information.

So, switching to the Date type is preferred.

In schema validation, since JSON does not support date types, it is sometimes easier to validate the string format the MongoDB is expecting as a date. Using a tool like [JSONSchema](https://jsonschema.net/login) gives the following:

```
"properties": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$"
}
```

This will verify that the JSON correctly represents the date in the form `2020-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Comment: If the OP is looking to add a pymongo datetime.datetime type, the drivers will map this to a BSON `date` type, not a string.